Trying to understand the role of usePathname in a footer component in next js
I'm new to Next js and am trying to finish a website I had paid someone to build but disappeared on me before completing.
The footers on the website built with Next js are appearing on the Home page but not on any of the other pages.
After doing some research I discovered it was because the footer component contains usePathname (as you see in the following code) which only works on client side components and the components folder is in the App directory.
const Footer = () => {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  if (pathname !== "/") return null;

  return (
    <footer className="py-[66px] bg-black min-h-[326px] flex">

I understand that usePathname is a Client Component hook that lets you read the current URL's pathname as stated on the Next js website but why is that needed in a footer component and why does removing it cause other components (like one on my Home page) to disappear?
I removed the following two lines of code and the footer component appeared as it is supposed to but then a component with a set of hyperlinked images on my Home page disappeared.
const pathname = usePathname();

  if (pathname !== "/") return null;

I expected the Footer component to appear as it did but can't understand why it caused the other component on my Home page to disappear.
Below is the entire footer component.


"use client";
import React from "react";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
const Footer = () => {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  if (pathname !== "/") return null;

  return (
    <footer className="py-[66px] bg-black min-h-[326px] flex">
      <div className="flex md:flex-row md:gap-0 gap-20 flex-col justify-between flex-1 max-w-screen-1440px mx-auto lg:pl-[106px] lg:pr-[270px] md:px-16 sm:px-12 px-4">
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-between">
          <img src="/footer.gif" alt="" />
          <p className="textwhite text-sm">© 2010 — 2020</p>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 flex md:justify-end lg:gap-20 md:gap-12 gap-10">
          <div className="flex flex-col gap-6">
            <h5 className="text-sm text-white font-bold">Navigate</h5>
            <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
              <span className="text-white text-sm">Buildings</span>
              <span className="text-white text-sm">Neighborhoods</span>
              <span className="text-white text-sm">Articles</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  );
};

export default Footer;



codesandbox link

can you add the complete footer component

can you provide a code sandbox, I guess its something with the image tag
can you please try this with image componenet.
import Image from 'next/image'
 
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <Image
      src="/profile.png"
      width={500}
      height={500}
      alt="Picture of the author"
    />
  )
}

Edited footer woring on the home page
import Image from "next/image";
import React from "react";

const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <footer className="py-[66px] bg-black min-h-[326px] flex">
      <div className="flex md:flex-row md:gap-0 gap-20 flex-col justify-between flex-1 max-w-screen-1440px mx-auto lg:pl-[106px] lg:pr-[270px] md:px-16 sm:px-12 px-4">
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-between">
          <Image width={40} height={40} src="/footer.gif" alt="" />
          <p className="textwhite text-sm">© 2010 — 2020</p>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 flex md:justify-end lg:gap-20 md:gap-12 gap-10">
          <div className="flex flex-col gap-6">
            <h5 className="text-sm text-white font-bold">Navigate</h5>
            <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
              <span className="text-white text-sm">Loft Buildings</span>
              <span className="text-white text-sm">Neighborhoods</span>
              <span className="text-white text-sm">Articles</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col gap-6">
            <h5 className="text-sm text-white font-bold">Legal</h5>
            <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
              <span className="text-white text-sm">Terms & Conditions</span>
              <span className="text-white text-sm">Privacy Policy</span>
              <span className="text-white text-sm">Cookie Policy</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  );
};

export default Footer;



I've added the codesandbox link. I'm sorry, what exactly do you want me to do with the image component you provided?

I updated the footer with the next/image and made it a server component; The website is working perfectly; can you check the sandbox? and also updated the above code

Yes, it's working on the Home page as it was before but not on any of the internal pages such as /neighborhoods or /idx. When I remove the two lines of code related to usePathname the footer works on the internal pages as it should but then the Neighborhoods.tsx component that displays the neighborhood images on the Home page disappears.

I removed the usePathname code, but I can view the neighourhood images
